# Why does the C# release build contain debug info

Tags: c#, .net, disassembly

While disassembling my C# program (release build), I noticed that it contained the names of the functions and the variables I used in the project (that I believe to be debug info, correct me if I'm wrong).

Can someone please explain why is it there and if it is necessary for the program.

Comment: Well names of types and members are preserved in the compiled assembly of course. Also, you can choose to deploy pdb files along with your assemblies or not, no matter if it's a debug or release build. You should always include the pdb files for more detailed exceptions.

Comment: If you are talking about fields/properties/methods, then you are mistaken. This is not debug info, but necessary meta-data enabling (late) binding and reflection in the CLR...

Comment: @HimBromBeere What type of code do you want here? :)

Comment: The names of classes and members are not debug info -- .NET (managed) languages can always rely on reflection metadata being available, unlike a language like C, where things are broken down into their lowest machine components with no further data if debugging information is omitted. Local variable names are sort-of debug info in that meaningful names are optional (and can't be reflected), but the compiler still chooses to include them. Third-party tools like obfuscators exist to change the names to "meaningless" ones, but they cannot outright remove the metadata, since .NET requires it.

Comment: Okay, I misread the question. Anyway it should be closed as it is simply based upon a whrong assumption.

Comment: Why do you think member-names are just debug-info? How would any client of your assembly use it if the names were not part of the compiled project?

Comment: .NET languages are compiled to CIL, which still contains the original names. Maybe you want to read up on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do method names get compiled into the EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413311/do-method-names-get-compiled-into-the-exe)

Comment: @Jeroen_Mostert Very interesting, I will check those Third-party tools, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three levels of what you call "debug info" in managed code.

1. **Included Metadata**: This includes all exposed namespaces, names and types (it doesn't include things like local variable names).  It gets bundled in the assembly and allows consumers of that code to know how to refer to the code and reference it.  In C/C++ land, this level of metadata gets carted around in *H files*.  In COM land, you get *type libraries*.  All assemblies get this - they can't be consumed without it.
2. **Symbols Files** (aka *PDB files*).  This is extended information about internal names, line numbers, etc.  Debuggers consume this information to make debugging work better.  You can create PDB files for both a "debug build" or a "release build" (or another other kind of build).  This is controlled by settings on the *Advanced Build Settings* dialog box accessible from the *Build* tab of the project properties.  By default, release builds get set to *PDB Only* while debug builds get set to *Full* (which I believe may put more information directly in the assembly).  PDB files aren't as important in managed code as they are in C/C++ land.  There, debugging is nearly impossible without a matching PDB file.
3. **Defining the *DEBUG* constant**: (set on the *Build* tab of a project's properties).  This #defined constant is used as a switch to include (or not include) Debug-only code.  Code may work subtly different with or without this constant defined.

Comment: .NET metadata in fact includes *everything*, even if not publicly exposed. (Or, if you prefer, .NET considers everything "publicly exposed" to a client with sufficient determination.) This is radically different from the closed-world assumption in some unmanaged languages.

Comment: Yeah, I stated that incorrectly.  What's missing in the metadata are things like the names of local variables.  I'll edit the answer.  Thanks.